# Inputting string into multidimensional array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make an array that hold multiple user input strings, I've tired structs and dynamic arrays and it does not work

I tried making a struct that holds a string, and tried making array of struct and it didn't work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>



using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rows;
    cin >> rows;
    string **arr = new string*[rows];
    for( int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        arr[i]= new string[1];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        getline(cin, arr[i][0]);
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        cout << arr[i][0] << '\n';
    }


    for( int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        delete [] arr[i];
    }
    delete [] arr;
return 0;
}
```

it allows rows + 1 inputs then crashes

Comment: why don't you use vectors?

Comment: prefer `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: The second level of indirection here is worthless. If you really want to use a dynamic sequence of `std::string`, you should use `std::vector<std::string>` as stated earlier. For this code, however, `arr` should be `std::string *arr = new std::string[rows];`, all referrals to `arr[i][0]` should be simply `arr[i]`, and the last for loop should be completely thrown out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use std::vector and std:string types to easily get the job done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rows;
    cin >> rows;
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::string s;

    // flush cin
    std::getline(std::cin, s);


    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, s);
        vec.push_back(s);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        cout << vec[i] << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @WhozCraig correct, modified accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: @JackWilliam great, then you may mark my answer as best answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

should be done in case of error, not in regular cases.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/q2DSyq)

Comment: This doesn't answer OP:s question at all, does it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I doesn't reproduce the "crash", but incorrect output, with provided fix, I got expected result (as shown in Demo). So even if OP style is *bad*, I don't see UB or similar.